# A block of code that is suppose to cause a bus error executes fine

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, bus-error

I am currently reading Expert C Programmign - Deep C Secrets. On page 164 where the author was explaining Bus Error and Segmentation fault , he showed this line of code

```
union { 
  char a[10];
  int i;
} u ;

int * p = ( int * ) &(u.a[1]);
*p = 17; /* the misaligned addr in p causes a bus error */
```

The above code is suppose to trigger a bus error, but when i ran it, it ran fine without any error. The author gave the below explanation

> This causes a bus error because the array/int union ensures that character array "a" is also at a reasonably aligned address for an integer, so "a+1" is definitely not. We then try to store 4 bytes into an address that is aligned only for single-byte access. A good compiler will warn about misalignment, but it cannot spot all occurrences.

My understanding of the above statement is that , `char` is 1 byte and we are trying to place an `int` which is 4 byte on an index of `char a[10]` hence a bus error will occur ( am not sure if my understanding is right or wrong )

My question is why is the above code not causing a bus error.

**Note:** Am not a CS student,simple explanations will help.

**Note:** A question that looks smiliar to this question have already been asked, but am only specific to the above block of code.

Comment: "I have this book that say I am not allowed to drive at 100km/h in a 30km/h zone. But I did anyhow and didn't get arrested. Why didn't I get arrested?"

Comment: I could see a bus error and segfault much more realistically if `a` were a pointer (e.g. `char *a;`). In either case you have `i` which takes roughly 1/2 the storage available, but if you changed `i` in this case to a value outside your valid memory block - bus error/segfault.

Comment: What architecture and OS are you using? If you are using intel then you will not notice any difference (at worst a few nanoseconds slower for an extra memory fetch). If you are using ARM/PowerPC/MIPS etc with linux then you will probably find that the kernel has been configured to do an automatic "fixup". Look up "/proc/cpu/alignment" for details on how to control kernel behaviour and view a count of fixups.

Comment: So many uninformed answers and comments on this one...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe that the book is mistaken. The code causes undefined behaviour. Expecting any certain behaviour from it is therefore flawed. Also note that not all architectures can cause bus errors. If the book doesn't explain this fact, that doesn't speak for it either.

Comment: Yes - this is one case where book-burning is acceptable.

Comment: @MartinJames - That's wasteful. But one can always do with scrap/toilet paper.

Comment: The book is not necessarily mistaken but may be incomplete. This isn't a problem on most intel CPU architectures (which handle the problem in hardware) but is on many 32-bit CPUs architectures used in embedded systems e.g. ARM, MIPS, PowerPC. Often the OS kernel (e.g. linux) may be configured to catch the fault and perform a "fixup". This is very inefficient but probably acceptable for most user applications. The overhead is not acceptable for real time applications and drivers and IIRC the linux kernel doesn't fixup errors triggered by the kernel itself.

Comment: Maybe, @Dipstick. The point that makes the difference is whether the code causes undefined behaviour or not. If the code causes UB and the book suggests that this reliably causes a bus error, even with the implied assumption of a CPU that detects them, then the book is most certainly mistaken. I don't rule out that cross-reading and selective quoting makes this look like a fault in the book.

Comment: @Ulrich Eckhardt - The book is from the early 1990s and is describing the Sun SPARC architecture and does mention "especially RISC architectures" in relation to memory alignment issues. The book needs burning due to age but the issues are still very relevant. Also to say the behaviour is undefined isn't really helpful; often different code is used depending on the architecture being compiled for. The linux kernel uses `#define CONFIG_HAVE_EFFICIENT_UNALIGNED_ACCESS` for this.

Comment: The comments telling you to wipe your butt with this book and then burn it (presumably in that order) are a little harsh. A better way to put it would have been "you could reasonably expect your program to crash at this point". I believe an x86 cpu would let this slide (at the cost of performance). I'm certain an 8080 would. Ulrich's answer is the correct one, however. "Undefined behavior" is often pronounced "here there be dragons". The system is allowed to do *anything* it wants at this point, including succeed.

Comment: @Dipstick, yes a Sun computer would have gotten a bus error here. If that book was specifically about Suns, then it is correct. 680x0 cpus require 16-bit alignment, and Sparc requires 32-bit. I was actually *at* Sun during the transition between 680x0 and Sparc, and there were a zillion alignment bugs discovered and fixed at that time.

Answer (score 2):

> My understanding of the above statement is that , char is 1 byte and we are trying to place an int which is 4 byte on an index of char a[10] hence a bus error will occur ( am not sure if my understanding is right or wrong )

The problem is not the size of `char` or `int`, but their alignment. Generally, architectures are finicky about the addresses you load data/code from, for example you might only be able to load a 16-bit integer from an address that is a multiple of 16-bit or a function must always start on a 4 byte boundary.

If you don't observe this, the processor might read wrong data or punish you with an exception. The OS then could emulate it using multiple aligned accesses or pass it through as a `SIGBUS` to the user application. The latter being what the author probably experiences on his setup.

**How does all this relate to C?**

What you have is undefined behavior. The interaction of processor, memory controller, compiler, OS and nasal demonic spawns in your vicinity will all have an effect on what effect this has (if at all). On your computer, it's possible that the processor supports unaligned accesses natively, so it worked, but still it's something you can't rely on: it's simply **undefined**. (Especially with optimizations, these things can come back to bite you. Works for me™ isn't good enough to write well-defined C code!)

Answer (score 1):

The data you are trying to fetch straddles a 32-bit boundary so 2 memory fetches are required (but the compiler does not necessarily know this at compile time).

Note: The book is very old and is talking about 32 bit CPUs. For 64 bit you may have to change `int * p = ( int * ) &(u.a[1]);` to `int * p = ( int * ) &(u.a[5]);` so that all the data required can't be obtained in one memory fetch from an aligned address.

For backward compatibility reasons most Intel CPUs (and derivatives such as AMD) handle memory alignment errors automatically at the instruction level so you would not notice anything wrong (simplistically it automatically adds an extra read having locked the bus to make sure nothing is changed between reads).

On many other CPU architectures (ARM, PowerPC, MIPS, newer Intel architectures) the example code would have caused problems as described but now some operating systems, such as Linux, can be configured to automatically catch the fault and do a "fixup" allowing the program to carry on unaware there was a problem. With most programs this would probably go unnoticed by the user but is quite time consuming and would cause real problems in real time software and drivers.

Time critical code is often conditionally compiled to do or not do unaligned accesses according to the CPU architecture it is being compiled for. In linux the pseudo file "/proc/cpu/alignment" can be used to control kernel behaviour and view statistics about the number of "fixups".

Comment: Note that on ARM, it is actually optional to support unaligned loads and ARMv8 actually mandates that unaligned loads are supported as far as I know.